# java servlet how to get value from init() method and use them outside the method?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-axis, init

Help please I'm new on servlet 
I'm trying to initialize value on the init method and use them after
but I get nullpointerexception 
this is my classe Hello it contains 2 methods  init() and jdbcinfo()
i need to get data base connection once

```
 package com.Ws;
    //imports..    
    public class Hello extends HttpServlet {

        public static Connection con;


        @Override
        public void init() throws ServletException
        {





                  try {
                    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");  
                     con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:6543/Dbname","user","");


                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("--printStackTrace--"+e);

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("--printStackTrace2--"+e);
                }
              }


     }
    //I get nullpointerexception here con = null

        public String jdbcInfo(String req) {

            PreparedStatement statementT;

            try {




    connection =con;

                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(req);
                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

                while (result.next()) {

                    ///

                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("exception: Serveur base de donnée indosponnible");

            }



            if (res == "1")
                return res;
            else
                return "false";
        }



        }
```

my web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.Ws.Hello</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. You can not have `System.out.println("returned value"+name);` outside of a function.

Comment: you are not overriding contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) method also that is also one error!!

Comment: and where you are getting Exception??

Comment: have you debug with breakpoints in init and jdbcInfo to check that init is really being called before?

Comment: yes in init con = net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@1ecf457c
in jdbcinfo con = null

Comment: Not answering the question you were asking, but I thought I mention it anyways: you should not check out and use Connections like that. A Connection is not supposed to live as long as your servlet does. Instead, check out a connection right before you need it, and close it when you're done.

Comment: it's working fine when i try to  check out a connection right before I need it but i dont want to do connection after every request i want to retrieve connection only once when web sevice reboot and then use it when i call the jdbcinfo methode

Answer (score 0):

@geert3 is correct. You do not want to create a connection and save it in a  field in a servlet's `init()` method. Servlets are singletonscan handle requests from multiple threads, so all fields should reference objects that are deeply immutable and thread-safe. `Connection` objects are niether.

Instead, you should use a [database connection pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html). Don't build your own connection pool code; there are [many](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) [choices](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) [out](http://jolbox.com/) there. If you are running the code inside an application server, your application server might have built-in database pool support.

As for the particular problem with the code, the best way to trouble-shoot it is to look at the printed stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

> //I get nullpointerexception here con = null

Your Instance variable of Class Connection `con` can be null if it didn't get initialized . Now how can this be possible :

At this line

```
  Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

if jar file is not present in your class Path this line will throw `ClassNotFoundException` and in that case it comes out of try block without executing this line

```
  con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:6543/Dbname","user","");
```

and in this case your `con` will be null
So Just check if the jar file is actually present in your class path or not